# Django- update division of base template after post without reload

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I want to include notifications in my base template as it is there in stackoverflow top left corner. I know this can be done by making custom **template tag** or custom **context processor**.

Now my requirement is that I do not want to load notifications every time the page is loaded, rather I want to load notifications only when we click on the notifications icon.

I don't know what other code or script is required as I am new to jquery/ajax.

Please let me know if any other details are required. Thanks.

**Edit:**(adding following details)

context_prrocessors.py:

```
def notifications(request):
 if request.POST and request.is_ajax:
  notify_obj = #some logic here
  return {'notify_obj': notify_obj}
```

base.html (partial):

```
<div id="notify-div">
<form id="notify-form" method="post">
 <input type="submit" name="notify" value="Show notifications">
 {% csrf_token %}
</form>
{% for notify in notify_obj %}
 {{ notify.user.user_id.username }}, {{ notify.wish.wish_text }} - {{ notify.added }}
{% endfor %}
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#notify-form').submit(function() { // catch the form's submit event
            $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
                data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
                type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
                url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
                success: function(response) { // on success..
                    $('#notify-div').html(response); // update the DIV
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Please tell wht JS should I use here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you shouldn't mix in the same time the post form, template tags and Ajax excepted if your notifications are coming from the two ways (template-views and Ajax). If i was you I would do everything with Ajax+javascript only.

Replace your form with just a button containing a function in "onclick" attribute which will do the Ajax call to your notification view then update you div tag with the success callback.

```
<script>
    function loadNotification() {
        $.get( "/url/to/notifications", function( data ) {
            $( "#notify-form" ).html( data );
        });
    }
</script>

<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="loadNotification();" />
```

Also, I would use GET request instead of POST.

I hope I am clear enough ;-)

Comment: thanks a lot, this really helps. I was following a wrong a wrong approach. I was confused with GET and POST. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

I urge you to look at the [Django messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/), rather than write your own notification application. It is trivial to hook it up to a `$.get()` when necessary.